# Is Error.cshtml a partial view or what?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm refactoring all my partial views to use the leading underscore naming convention (didn't know about this convention when I got started, don't want to deviate from such a plain convention). But I've come across the generated (razor, C#) "Error.cshtml" view in \Views\Shared and I noticed it looks like it may be a partial view (no html / body tags) yet doesn't follow the convention:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h2>
    Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
</h2>
```

I also notice it doesn't specify a Layout, yet sets the `ViewBag.Title` property as if it were going to be used by a Layout. What's the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange. My generated Error.cshtml looks like a "normal" view with HTML body:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I think in your case the layout is not set to null, hence the default layout will be used that contains the HTML wrapping elements.
But it is still a "normal" view (not partial).

Comment: Interesting, and you are using MVC3?

Comment: Yes, I use MVC3. See my additions regarding the differences with your code.

Comment: I just created a new MVC3 project from scratch and confirmed that the Error.cshtml markup I posted in my question is the same.